# Can web server send data to desktop application without request?

Tags: java, json, swing, request

I have several PC's on each of them I set small swing application that get data with JSON request to one web server. Can I receive the data from web server without to send request to the web server, with other words can the Web server send the data without the Java application to ask for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough server resources 
you can consider usage of websockets.

Every PC can open a socket to the server. 
When you open the socket you need to send to the server, the pc's unique ID.
Then you need to store this ID in some database or file that will contain all online pc's and sockets .

Then the Server will be aware which pc's are online and which socket to use to communicate with this pc. After this you can send whatever information you need to this PC depending on your application.

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented in several ways. One common way would be to open a connection and do blocking read in the client application. On receiving something it will look like push from the server. Then you process the push and do another blocking read.

Another option would be doing regular checks if there is something for you on the web server. You set the retry interval frequent enough so it will look like real time push from your app point of view.

Answer (score 1):

If you use HTTP i think the smartest way is to drop the realtime requirement and use a thread that polls the server every 5 seconds. Keeping a HTTP Connection open all time is expensive as it blocks a request processor thread and limits the amount of clients you can have.

You might also consider moving to something like a registration mechanism if you really need near-realtime updates which is often not the case. You would have to open a Server on the clients and have the server push the updates after clients registered their Address with the server.